# Is the continuity of measures a topological continuity?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I am wondering if there is an implicit topology in a $\sigma$-algebra that makes any finite measure defined on it a continuous function, since in this context continuity means limit-preserving (when the measure is finite) as occurs with first countable spaces.

Comment: The discrete topology is a trivial example but you probably want something more interesting. For that the only thing that comes to mind is not quite the same thing: given a finite measure $m$ with all null sets empty, $d(A,B)=m(A \Delta B)$ is a metric, where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference. But that is going the other way.

Comment: $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of sequences of sets can be defined, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit , so you can define the limit whenever the two coincide. Moreover, if $A_n \to A$ in such sense, then $\mu(A_n)\to \mu(A)$ for any finite measure $\mu$. However I don't know if this notion of convergence is induced by a topology.

Comment: I guess you could always define the topology in an abstract way, i.e. you can consider all the possible finite measures as a collection of functions from your $\sigma$-algebra to $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the euclidean topology. Then you can consider the weak topology $\tau$ induced by this family of functions, i.e. the smallest topology that makes them continuous. However there is the possibility, as @Ian said, that such topology is the discrete one. So I guess the interesting question becomes to determine conditions under which this does not happen.

Comment: @Lucio yes, I've been thinking about the initial topology wrt the family of finite measures. It certainly would be interesting to meet sufficient conditions ensuring the induced topology is not the discrete one or perhaps have some representation of the open sets in term of the measures

Comment: By the very definition of weak topology, a neighbourhood basis for a set $A$ would be given by all sets of the form $\{B\in\sigma : \vert \mu_i(B) - \mu_i(A)\vert <\varepsilon_i \text{ for } i=1,\ldots ,n\}$ varying $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\varepsilon_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu_i$ measures. Without any structure on the $\sigma$-algebra I don't know how these could be done (the only measures you can use as test are convex combinations of dirac deltas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite surprisingly (to me at least) it turns out that the notion of convergence of sets given by $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ I mentioned earlier is the convergence induced by the weak topology of all finite measures. To see this I'll use the following characterizations:
$$x\in\liminf A_n \Leftrightarrow \exists\ N\in\mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } x\in A_n \text{ for all }n\geq N $$
$$x\in\limsup A_n \Leftrightarrow x\in A_n \text{ for infinitely many } n$$
Now assume $A_n$ is a sequence of sets in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, $A\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $A_n\to A$ in the sense of the weak topology, i.e. such that $\mu(A_n)\to\mu(A)$ for all $\mu$. Let $x\in A$ and consider $\mu=\delta_x$, then we must have $\delta_x(A_n)\to1$; since $\delta_x(A_n)$ takes only values $0$ and $1$, this implies that definitely $\delta_x(A_n)=1$ and so $x\in\liminf A_n$. Conversely, let $y\in\limsup A_n$ and take $\mu=\delta_y$, then we have $\delta_y(A)=\lim \delta_y(A_n)=\limsup \delta_y(A_n)=1$ and so $y\in A$. So we have obtained
$$ A\subset \liminf A_n\subset \limsup A_n\subset A$$
which implies $A=\lim A_n$ in the set limit sense. The inverse fact that if $A=\lim A_n$, then $\mu(A_n)\to\mu(A)$ for all finite measures, is well known (for example quoted in the wikipedia link) and can be proved using monotone properties of the measure.

An example of a non trivial convergent sequence is the following: assume $x, x_n$ are all elements of the space such that $\{x\}, \{x_n\}\in\mathcal{A}$ and $x_n\neq x, x_n\neq x_m$ for all  $n\neq m$. Consider the sets $A_n=\{x,x_n\}$. Then we have $\liminf A_n=\limsup A_n=\{x\}$ and so $A_n\to \{x\}$ but $A_n\neq \{x\}$ for all $n$.

The example above can be easily generalized whenever $\mathcal{A}$ contains a countable amount of pairwise disjoint sets (let $A_n$ be such sets, consider $B_n=A_0\cup A_n$ for $n\geq 1$, then $B_n\to A_0$). I think (but I don't have a proof of this) that such a sequence can aways be found if $\mathcal{A}$ is at least countable. Instead if $\mathcal{A}$ is finite then it will be generated by a finite partition of the space and in that case it's easy to see (take appropriate test measures $\mu$) that the weak topology induced on $\mathcal{A}$ is the discrete one.

Comment: This is very nice and ingenious! I'll take the time to read it completely and carefully before taking it as an answer

Comment: There is still something I'm not clear about but maybe that's just a topological fact of which I'm not aware of. The fact the limit of any convergent sequence in the set theoretic sense is preserved by finite measures implies that it is also preserved by every continuous function wrt this topology? And also, how do we know this topology is first countable?

Comment: @laflaca for the first question: it is a general fact that, given a family of functions $f_\alpha$, a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the weak topology induced by $f_\alpha$ if and only if $f_\alpha(x_n)\to f_\alpha(x)$ for all $\alpha$. Then it's a general fact that, if $x_n\to x$, then $g(x_n)\to g(x)$ for any $g$ continuous w.r.t. the topology

Comment: For the second question: maybe there is a misunderstanding, because I never stated that the topology is first countable. When I used the pedix $n$ I was implying I was talking about a sequence, so what I've provided is a characterization for convergent sequences, not convergent nets. In fact the problem is that if we considered an uncountable amount of elements, there wouldn't even be the guarantee that $\limsup A_\alpha$ and $\liminf A_\alpha$ were well defined, because we would need to take uncountable unions/ intersections and so they would not necessarily be in the $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, standard neighbourhood basis can be provided, but without any structure on the $\sigma$-algebra I don't know if there is a way to find a countable one; I don't think so. Anyway, the existence of non trivial convergent sequences implies that the topology is not the discrete one. Giving a characterization of converging nets would probably require more work.